# Unable to open an Excel file on a Windows 7 PC which opens on a Windows XP PC

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Several of our staff download data from a website as an excel (.xls) file. We are able to open the files in Excel 2007 on Windows XP PCs, but not on Windows 7 PCs.

When Trying to open the file we get the following messages:

```
Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xls'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.
```

Clicking on Yes leads to:

```
Unable to read file.
```

Followed by:

```
The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt.
```

Additional Info:

I tried disabling the anti-virus (Symantec Endpoint Protection), in case it was interfering some how.

Comment: Have you tried downloading with an alternate browser?  Have you tried creating/downloading th exact same document on a problem machine and a good machine and comparing their size/stats/md5sum?  Have you tried copying a file downloaded from one of the good machines to a problem machine and opening it?  Have you tried downloading on a bad machine and opening on a good machine?

Comment: @Zoredache - We're tied to using IE for support reasons, though I may try downloading a file via another browser to see if it makes a difference. We have many preexisting files created via XP machines plus files downloaded on the Win-7 PCs and the behavior is consistence i.e. works on XP but not on Win-7, regardless of the origin of the file.

Answer (score 1):

After initially being told "We've never heard of this issue" by the software vendor of the web app, we've now been told "It's a known issue and we'll fix in a future release."

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/the-file-is-corrupt-and-cannot-be-opened-error-on/93af59c1-946c-4f5f-83c1-bd6f58dbd94f?page=2) where this issue is solved for some users
Try this:
Go to File -> options
Then Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings
Then Protected view
uncheck the 3 options there and re-start Excel to test.

If that doesn't work, try to add the download location to the Trusted Locations section.

Comment: I didn't mean to dredge up an old question... I didn't even see the dates on it. It just came up on the list of questions.